# Installing munin-node in an AWS Instance running Amazon Linux

Tags: amazon-web-services, munin

Can I use the procedure described here (http://munin-monitoring.org/wiki/LinuxInstallation) for RedHat or I need to use a different one?

Comment: Couldn't you just try it? Amazon Linux is RedHat-compatible under the hood. Try the RHEL instructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

...additional text here to pad out to the 30 char minimum.

Comment: After trying that procedure. I found that in fact, it's easier than that. yum install sysstat, yum install munin-node. Thanks!